# How to determine endpoints of Arcs in GraphicsPath PathPoints and PathTypes arrays?

Tags: gdi+, bezier, graphicspath

I have the following PathPoints and PathTypes arrays (format: X, Y, Type):

```
-177.477900,  11021.670000, 1
-614.447200,  11091.820000, 3
-1039.798000, 10842.280000, 3
-1191.761000, 10426.620000, 3
-1591.569000, 10493.590000, 3
-1969.963000, 10223.770000, 3
-2036.929000, 9823.960000,  3
-2055.820000, 9711.180000,  3
-2048.098000, 9595.546000,  3
-2014.380000, 9486.278000,  3
```

Here is what this GraphicsPath physically looks like.  The 2 Arcs are very distinguishable:
[image]

I know that this GraphicsPath.PathData array was created by 2 AddArc commands.  Stepping through the code in the debugger, I saw that the first 4 PathData values were added by the first AddArc command, and the remaining 6 points were added by the 2nd AddArc command.

By examining the raw pathpoints/pathtype arrays (without previously knowing that it was 2 AddArc commands so I would know that I have 2 start and end points), I would like to determine to start and end point of each arc.

I have tried several Bezier calculations to 'recreate' the points in the array, but am at a loss to determine how to determine the separate start and end points.  It appears that GDI+ is combining the start/end point between the arcs (they are the same point and the arcs are connected), and I am losing the fact that one arc is ending and other one is starting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the GraphicsPathIterator class in combination with the GraphicsPath.SetMarkers method.

For example:

```
dim gp as new GraphicsPath
gp.AddArc(-50, 0, 100, 50, 270, 90) 'Arc1
gp.SetMarkers()
gp.AddArc(0, 25, 100, 50, 270, 90) 'Arc2
Dim iterator as New GraphicsPathIterator(gp)
Dim i as Integer = 0
Dim MyPts(3) As PointF
Dim temp as New GraphicsPath
Do until i > 2
   iterator.NextMarker(temp)
   MyPts(i) = temp.PathPoints(0)
   MyPts(i + 1) = temp.GetLastPoint()
  i += 2
Loop

'Free system resources...
iterator.Dispose()

temp.Dispose()

Arc1 -> start: MyPts(0); end: MyPts(1)
Arc2 -> start: MyPts(2); end: MyPts(3)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This might help as long as you actually can add markers when you create path. But that's not always possible. Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790862/how-to-determine-endpoints-of-arcs-in-graphicspath-pathpoints-and-pathtypes-arra/17339215#17339215) to better understand how `GraphicsPath` is constructed internally.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PathPointType Enum (System.Drawing.Drawing2D).
Value   Meaning
  0     Start (path)
  1     Line
  3     Bezier/Bezier3
  7     PathType Mask
 16     Dash Mode
 32     Path Marker
128     Close Subpath

Comment: That is what the 3rd number in my list above (the PathPointType).  The issue I have is that the is 2 Bezier/Bezier3 (PathPointType = 3) curves in the array above.  I need to figure out how to determine where to divide the array.  I know my adding the arc programatically that the '-1191.761000, 10426.620000, 3' value is the endpoint of the first arc and the start point of the second arc.  However, I need to figure out how to determine that programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

This one was bugging me a lot too! I had path created beyond my control without markers and couldn't figure out curve endpoints.

In this case you'd expect that the curve starts at `[i + 1]` but it is not! It turns out that GDI combines path points probably to make the points array shorter. In this case the curve points are: `[0], [1], [2], [3]`.

It seems that if `PathPointType.Start` or `PathPointType.Line` is followed by `PathPointType.Bezier`, then you have to treat the `PathPontType.Start` or `Path.PointType.Line` as a first point of your Bezier curve, so in your example it should be like this:

```
 -177.47, 11021.67, 1  // Draw line to this point AND use it as a Bezier start!
 -614.44, 11091.82, 3  // Second Bezier point
-1039.79, 10842.28, 3  // Third Bezier point
-1191.76, 10426.62, 3  // Fourth Bezier point AND first point of the next Bezier!
-1591.56, 10493.59, 3  // Second Bezier point
-1969.96, 10223.77, 3  // Third Bezier point
-2036.92,  9823.96, 3  // Fourth Bezier point AND first point of the next Bezier!
-2055.82,  9711.18, 3  // Second Bezier point
-2048.09,  9595.54, 3  // Third Bezier point
-2014.38,  9486.27, 3  // Fourth Bezier point
```

So, when analysing `PathPoints` array point by point, you have to also check current **and** following indices. The docs on [PatPointType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ch9cxht.aspx) might come in handy. In most cases you can probably ignore additional data stored on bits other than the first three (these three define `Start`, `Line` and `Bezier`). The only exception is `CloseSubpath` but it's irrelevant if you consider the next advice.

It's also worth noting that if you have a complex path that consists of huge number of `PathPoints` then it might be handy to split the path into chunks using [GraphicsPathIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspathiterator.aspx). This simplifies the whole procedure as `PathPointType.CloseSubpath` can be ignored - it will be always the last point of your `GraphicsPath` chunk.

A quick look into Reflector or [here](http://blog.red-stars.net/technology/programming/csharp/system-drawing-drawing2d-pathpointtype-defined/) might be helpful if you want to better understand `PointTypes` array.