# How to convert GDI+ GraphicsPath to HTML5 canvas Path?

Tags: c#, html, html5-canvas, gdi+

Is there a library that would help to convert GDI+ `GraphicsPath` to HTML5 canvas Path? Or do I have to manually run through all `GraphicsPath.PathPoints` and `GraphicsPath.PathTypes` to emit corresponding HTML5 code (if so please share any hints)?

Comment: Unless it's a small 1-off project I would build a tiny parser inputting either the raw GraphicsPath.Add...() method code or the PathPoints + PathTypes. It's been a while since I used GDI, but I think I remember that addPie and addText are the few "non-html-canvas" gdi path methods. Fairly straightforward, no?

Comment: @markE It's probably a single project, but some paths are very complex (created from text) and contain thousands of curves.

Comment: When you say "created from text", do you mean .AddString() or do you mean someone created text-like paths using a bunch of .AddCurve()?  BTW, are you staring with the PathPoints + PathTypes  data or are you starting with the code that generated the path(s)?

Comment: @markE I mean `.AddString()`. I would like to make things simple and use just PathPoints + PathTypes. I have access to the code that generated the GraphicsPaths but I would rather not touch it. Another issue are fonts - I can't make them public, so I want to use curves instead of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything useful. Some people suggested using SVG as a way to "transport" curves from GDI to Canvas, but I couldn't find any decent SVG library for .NET. It took me quite some time to understand how the data inside `GraphicsPath` is stored because it is not as straightforward as you might think. [This is what I've came up to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17339215/899092).

Knowing how GraphicsPath actually work I've managed to recreate it using bunch of HTML5 functions: `.moveTo()`, `.lineTo()` and `.bezierCurveTo()`. The result was pretty neat although final string building takes some time and resulting JS files sometimes contain tenths of thousands lines of code if source GraphicsPath represents long text written with fancy font. Surprisingly Firefox handles them without problems.

I won't paste the code that I'm using as it is nothing special as long as you read and understand [my answer from another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17339215/899092).

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an answer, but I think the idea itself is very good. If one were to create a GDI+ to HTML5 library, it would allow Microsoft to move forward with a 2D UI that directly renders HTML instead of using the GDI+ APIs. By necessity, Microsoft would also need to make a GDI+ (maybe Silverlight also) to HTML library for backwards compatibility. In any case, it would lead to lower consumer costs for windows laptops and at the same time, unify all 2D app-dev for Windows under a single framework.